# Implement a 2D split() function

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, split

I'm trying to create a `split()` function which splits a `char*` into a 2D array or `char**`

```
void split(char* str, char d, char** into)
{
    if(str != NULL || into != NULL)
    {
        int n = 0;
        int c = 0;
        for(int i = 0; str[c] != '\0'; i++,c++)
        {
            into[n][i] = str[c];
            if(str[c] == d)
            {
                into[n][i] = '\0';
                i = 0;
                ++n;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char** sa = (char**)malloc(50*sizeof(char*));
    memory.allocarr(sa, 512, 50);
    split("Hello;World;", ';', sa);
    puts(sa[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

`memory.allocarr` is a pointer in a structure that points to the below function

```
void memory_allocate_array(char** pointers, int bytes, int slots) // memory.allocarr
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i <= slots)
    {
        pointers[i] = (char*)calloc(1, bytes);
        ++i;
    }
}
```

My function **only** splits and fills the **first** slot of the array (`sa[0]`)

```
puts(sa[0]); // Prints "Hello"

puts(sa[1]); // Prints ""

puts(sa[2]); // Prints "" ...
```

I tried debugging it

```
    for(int i = 0; str[c] != '\0'; i++,c++)
    {
        printf("n:%d\ti:%d\tc:%d\n",n,i,c);
        into[n][i] = str[c];
        if(str[c] == d)
        {
            into[n][i] = '\0';
            i = 0;
            ++n;
        }
        puts(into[n]);
    }
```

> **Output**

```
n:0     i:0     c:0
H
n:0     i:1     c:1
He
n:0     i:2     c:2
Hel
n:0     i:3     c:3
Hell
n:0     i:4     c:4
Hello
n:0     i:5     c:5

n:1     i:1     c:6

n:1     i:2     c:7

n:1     i:3     c:8

n:1     i:4     c:9

n:1     i:5     c:10

n:1     i:6     c:11
```

I still don't get what exactly went wrong, can you help me figure it out?

Comment: Yes, the "wrong" part is that when `n:1`, `i` starts with `1` instead of `0`.

Comment: (therefore `into[1][0] == 0`)

Comment: Anyway, very well-written question (although is unlikely to be helpful to anyone else) - take a +1. (side note: You [don't need to tag in title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems.

The first one is a minor one, it's a logic error:

```
if(str != NULL || into != NULL)
```

you want to do the splitting only when both `str` and `into` are not `NULL`. So
the correct condition is:

```
if(str != NULL && into != NULL)
```

Remember that `a || b` is equivalent to `!a && !b`.

The second problem is here:

```
if(str[c] == d)
{
    into[n][i] = '\0';
    i = 0; // <--- here
    ++n;
}
```

the idea is OK, but when you reset `i` to 0, the next iteration is executed, but
prior to that the `i++,c++` of the `for` loop **is executed** as well. For the
second, third, fourth, etc. iteration `i` starts with 1. Because you use `calloc` for allocating
your memory, the `into[n][i]` are all 0 and `into[n][i] = str[c];` in the second
iteration is doing `into[n][1] = str[c]`. So you are creating this string:

```
            +----+---+---+---+---+---+----+
into[n]:    | \0 | W | o | r | l | d | \0 |
            +----+---+---+---+---+---+----+

for all n >= 1
```

The first character in the string is already the '\0'-terminating byte, so
`puts` prints an empty line.

How to fix it? Like this:

```
if(str[c] == d)
{
    into[n][i] = '\0';
    i = -1;
    ++n;
}
```

So that when the second, third, etc iteration start, `i` is 0.

I took your code and made the fix and I got `Hello` and `World` like it should
be.

Also don't forget to free all the allocated memory. Write a function that does
that takes the the double-pointer as an argument and it's length, something like
this:

```
void free_string_matrix(char **matrix, size_t len)
{
    if(matrix == NULL || *matrix == NULL)
        return;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        free(matrix[i]);

    free(matrix);
}
```

Comment: @KiraSama the `calloc` call is not the problem, the wrong index was the problem. And for allocating space for strings I always use `calloc` because it set the allocated memory to 0.

Comment: I meant debugging, If I used `malloc`, at least it would print the two strings `sa[0]` and `sa[1]` without **terminating** them and I'd have understood the problem earlier when I see some *random char* at the `0` index of `sa[1]` like `?World`, I use `calloc` for the same reason